# Mysql date formatting and ordering

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table where the dating is not standard and need to somehow organise the rows by date and time.

```
job_date    |    job_time
=========================
12/12/2012  |   10.30am  
11/10/2012  |    9.00pm  
14/11/2012  |   11.50pm
```

Is there any way of formatting these within mysql. I have looked at the DATE_FORMAT() function but the examples I have found don't seem to relate to the format within my tables.

Comment: can you define `format`? what formatting do you want?

Comment: Do you store these dates and times as stings? Please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;`

Comment: They are saved as strings

Answer (score 2):

SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(job_date,' ',job_time), 'Y-m-d H:i:s') AS date_format from  table ORDER BY date_format DESC

Comment: This is slowly getting there but I need to order by both time and date - I have tried combining but this still does not get the desired results: "SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(job_date,'%m/%d/%Y')AS real_job_date, STR_TO_DATE(time_id,'%h:%i%p')AS real_job_time FROM agent_booking_db WHERE user_id='$id' AND completed=0 ORDER BY real_job_date, real_job_time DESC"

Answer (score 2):

The key method is `STR_TO_DATE`.
I will give you two solutions :

first : if you **don't** want to change your database :

```
SELECT jobdate, STR_TO_DATE(job_time,'%h:%i%p')AS real_job_time FROM yourtable ORDER BY real_job_time;
```

second : if you **can** modify your database, use the TIME format :

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
    MODIFY COLUMN job_time TIME NOT NULL;
UPDATE yourtable SET job_time = STR_TO_DATE(job_time,'%h:%i%p');
```

and to select

```
SELECT jobdate,job_time FROM yourtable ORDER BY job_time
```

I think the second solution is by far the best and that you *should* choose it.

Comment: I might add that you need a seriously strong reason to want to keep your dates and times as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously storing it as a correct date would be a lot better and result in quicker queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY substr(job_date, -4), substr(job_date, 4, 2), substr(job_date, 1, 2)
```

Comment: it's bogus as hours have no leading 0